# pytest: Realizing all fixture permutations as a test's input

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test case that involves a rather large cartesian product(thousands of permutations) of a dictionary's keys/values. The function under test will spit out a `list` of MD5 sums each with a 1-1 correspondence to a given permutation.

*Function under test:*

```
 def get_all_perms():
     ... return big list of MD5 sums
```

I am trying to use pytest fixtures to generate the permutation space. As such I have a bunch of composed fixtures as follows:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[True,False])
def build_pair_1(request):
    return ('KEY_1', request.param)

@pytest.fixture(params=[True,False])
def build_pair_2(request):
    return ('KEY_2', request.param)

@pytest.fixture(params=[True,False])
def build_pair_3(request):
    return ('KEY_3', request.param)

@pytest.fixture
def build_dict(build_pair_1, build_pair_2, build_pair_3)

    return dict([
            build_pair_1,
            build_pair_2,
            build_pair_3,
        ])

@pytest.fixture
def get_sums(build_dict):
    return sum(build_dict)
```

This does an excellent job of creating all the permutations. But if my understanding is correct and I add `get_sums` to a test as an argument I'll get a test execution per sum. What I need to do is take the resulting set of permutations from `get_sums`, stuff it into a list, and compare it to the result of my function under test. Something akin to...

```
def test_result_of_get_all_perms:
    result = get_all_perms()
    for sum in get_sums():
        assert sum in result
```

Is there a way to iterate over the result of a fixture?

Comment: Do you want to have one test per permutation or not?

Comment: Why use pytest fixtures and not [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)?

Comment: fixtures seemed like a pretty natural solution to the problem. Its composable, I get a test per fixture perm with a name to indicate which perm failed. I ended up just checking for a `contains` in the result of the fixture. Sort of lame cause I build the entire context for each test run. If there was a way to iterate over the fixtures result I could pin point exactly which sum was failing while only building the context once.

Comment: maybe you should update the Q with your actual code, because it's still not clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: My actual code isn't any different from this example. The only difference is it has an implementation for `sum` and the obfuscated function names and keys have my real names. Clearly an `iterable` that is the result of composing all the fixtures exists somewhere and its iterated over invoking the test for each perm. I just want to know if there is some way for me get a handle on this `iterable` so I can iterate over it myself.